# Deleting Vectors By Index Using Iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a quick question that's giving me some grief. As part of a much larger project, I want to scan a vector for elements that are 0 and, when I find them, delete them. I'm curious as to why the following is alright:

```
if (playerVec[5] == 0)
```

But this is not:

```
for(vector<Player>::iterator it = playerVec.begin(); it != playerVec.end(); ++it) {

if(playerVec[it] == 0) { //Invalid if condition

}
```

I assume it has to do with the factor that it is an iterator, but how else could I approach the deletion within a for loop? Do I need another variable for indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
std::erase(std::remove(playerVec.begin(), playerVec.end(), 0), playerVec.end());
```

The reason your condition is invalid is because an iterator isn't an index. It's like a pointer to an element, and you can use it as such (with `*` and `->` to access the element). For example, the correct condition in your code would be `if(*it == 0)`.

Comment: I understand remove, but trying to wrap it in erase like you suggested gives a syntax error saying it is undefined. I have included both string and algorithm libraries, so I'm wondering what the issue is. EDIT: Actually, when I build it, the compiler throws an error then, even for the remove line itself. I have a feeling it's due to the multiple data member nature of Player.

Comment: Nvm, I got it with this, just needed to edit the syntax a little. Inside the outer brackets, after the remove operation, should be ,playerVec.end(). Thanks for the point in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

`it` is an iterator, not an index. If you want to get the index from a (random access) iterator `it`, just do:

```
 it - playerVec.begin()
```

However, in your case you just want to dereference the iterator to get the value of the pointed element:

```
if (*it == 0) { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, mostly understood. The auto keyword is somewhat fuzzy to me, though I have heard of its use before. Is it strictly necessary in this case? If so, why?

Comment: @Rome_Leader: It is not strictly necessary, and in fact I edited the answer, because what I was suggesting was somewhat stupid. Please disregard it :)

Comment: Haha, fair enough! I have a feeling I will need to go elsewhere to overload the == operator though, since the compiler currently complains it has no definition for Player Type == Int Type. Am I right here?

Comment: I think is is not always right  to compare a `Player` object with 0.(depends on how `Player` class is defined)

Comment: Player class has several data members, of which I only care about one in this vector case. If I overload == to check on that operator, it should function, I think. I'll try it anyway; report back with any errors. Otherwise, how would you suggest I go about deleting the elements in the vector I desire?

Comment: *Notice, however, that erasing elements from a loop* I see you've tried to erase elements from within a loop while writing this answer.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: lol, leftover from a previous attempt to cover more than I actually wanted to. I should definitely get some sleep and stop answering :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) function to remove elements within a container that meet some criteria:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool isZero(Player p) {
  return p == 0;
}

playerVec.erase(std::remove_if(playerVec.begin(), playerVec.end(), isZero),
                playerVec.end());
```

Comment: For this case, you can just use `std::remove` and pass the value `0`.  No need for a custom function.  Also, in order to actually delete the elements from the container, you need to capture the return value of the algorithm and pass it to `vector::erase`.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely want the elements gone altogether. So erase seems to be the way to go. I think I can do that, still concerned about the condition for deletion, though

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks, I completely forgot about using erase.